# Unable to send keys to div element Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi am trying to populate value to text box (check image below) using xpath.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                                        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='CzI8E']")));
                                        actions.click();
                                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                                        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text']")));//_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text
                                        actions.sendKeys(WhatsappConstants.TEXT_MESSAGE);
                                        actions.build().perform();
```

But i am getting this exception

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP`

Other stackoverflow answers said to use firefox driver but in my case i need you use chrome only.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any textbox in the dom hierarchy. Perhaps you need to click the div you focused first then it injects a textbox there - just a guess.

Comment: @SiddhantSwami if you see my code above, I have already clicked on the element

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Can you share the URL of web site ?

Comment: What is value of WhatsappConstants.TEXT_MESSAGE? Does it contain any non-unicode symbols (chinese, russian alphabet, emoji, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of the Chromedriver, see http://crbug.com/chromedriver/2269 for the bug report in the official bug tracker.

What you could do is to only limit yourself to supported characters, basically those from: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html

Alternatively, you could simulate input instead of really sending the keys using front-end JS snippet like the following:

```js
(function (element, text) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(text, function (char) {
        element.value += char;
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown"));
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress"));
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("input"));
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup"));
    });
}).apply(null, arguments);
```

Which you then call using the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html):

```java
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(JS_CODE, element, text);
```

The snippet works on elements with a writable `.value` property, it could be extended to support `contenteditable` elements.

Note that the fields of the events are set to their defaults, including key codes and such, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent Also you might have to add additional events to be triggered to even better simulate user input.

Comment: "it could be extended to support **contenteditable** elements." - How?

Comment: @Gal Bracha: TBH, I cannot remember anymore, I guess changing the `innerHTML` should suffice but one might think about line-breaks (e.g. doing `<br>`s unless the `white-space` CSS property is set to certain non-standard values) and be smart about wrapping elements (e.g. `<p>`). Should you have a specific use case where this is a problem then it might be worth its own question IMHO.

Comment: I was managed to do it like so -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60485967/395804

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I solve it in this way.
First, you should add any text to this div with `JavascriptExecutor` , and then clear this text and use selenium's `sendKeys` method

```
WebElement inputDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_path_to_div"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("document.querySelector('your_selector_to_div').innerText='aaa'");

inputDiv.clear();
inputDiv.sendKeys(subject);
```