# How to set content into mui-rte with selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, material-ui, webdriverwait, draftjs

I am using mui-rte rich text editor (https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte) in a react project. I am not able to figure out how to input text to the rte input area when writing a selenium webdriver integration test.

As I understand correctly, mui-rte is a materia-ui wrapper of draftjs. The react code is simply:

```
<MUIRichTextEditor
        onChange={onChange}
        value={initial}
        {...rest}
/ >
```

This generates the following html elements:

```
<div id="mui-rte-container" class="MUIRichTextEditor-container-73">
<div id="mui-rte-toolbar" class="MUIRichTextEditor-toolbar-84">
    ...
</div>
<div id="mui-rte-editor" class="MUIRichTextEditor-editor-75">
    <div id="mui-rte-editor-container" class="MUIRichTextEditor-hidePlaceholder-79 MUIRichTextEditor-editorContainer-76">
        <div class="DraftEditor-root">
            <div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer">
                <div aria-describedby="placeholder-9mnek" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline:none;user-select:text;-webkit-user-select:text;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word" contenteditable="true">
                    <div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="7kjuh" data-offset-key="8a2rc-0-0">
                        <div data-offset-key="8a2rc-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr">
                            <span data-offset-key="8a2rc-0-0">
                                <br data-text="true">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can easily find any of the element but when I try this for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

rte_editor = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id))
    )
rte_input = bio_rte.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='textbox']")
rte_input.send_keys("Hello")
```

I get:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

With all elements that I have tried.

What is the correct way to input text into draft.js rte with selenium-webdriver in python? I am quite new to selenium+webdriver and any help will be appreciated, be it in python, JavaScript or other flavor of selenium-webdriver API.

I have a sample project here: https://github.com/vessper/formik-mui-rte-example

#### update:

Including the stack trace from the error:

```
self = <test.TestBase testMethod=test_input_text_in_rte>

    def test_input_text_in_rte(self):
        rte_input = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
>               (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" and @role="textbox"]'))
        )

test.py:25: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="38c21bf5-27ea-499d-9831-e8755a10f57a")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable object at 0x7f7115fe7198>, message = ''

    def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

../../../.virtualenvs/ml2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:80: TimeoutException
================================================================= 1 failed in 24.70s ==================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a **draft.js** rich text editor with a **contenteditable** div

```
async sendKeysToContentEditableDiv(element, text) {
    const script = `var txtarea = arguments[0],txt = arguments[1];
    txtarea.dispatchEvent(new Event("focus"));
    var txtEvt = document.createEvent("TextEvent");
    txtEvt.initTextEvent("textInput", true, true, null, txt);
    txtarea.dispatchEvent(txtEvt);     
    txtarea.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"));`;
    await this.driver.executeScript(script, element, text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element so to locate and send a *character sequence* to the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content[role='textbox']"))).send_keys("Vess_Perfanov")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notranslate public-DraftEditor-content' and @role='textbox']"))).send_keys("Vess_Perfanov")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As the `click()` is still not invoked with *WebDriverWait* you can use *ActionChains* as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content[role='textbox']"))).send_keys("Vess_Perfanov")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).send_keys("Vess_Perfanov").perform()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notranslate public-DraftEditor-content' and @role='textbox']"))).send_keys("Vess_Perfanov")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).send_keys_to_element(element, "Vess_Perfanov").perform()
  ```

Comment: Hello. This seems to be in the right direction but it still does not work. The code timeout if I do nothing, but if I click on the element in the webdriver browser while the wait happens then the text gets input. I implemented the test here: [https://github.com/vessper/formik-mui-rte-example/blob/master/test.py]. What else do I have to do? click() doesn't work either but what is the correct way to focus on this element?

Comment: @VessPerfanov Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: thanks again, after going through the sequence very carefully I noticed that I have omitted a overlay label element that material-UI puts above the textbox. This element has to be focused and clicked using one of your suggestions. This is my omission, I am sorry. I have a working test now. I guess I should post the correct answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inline label element from Material-UI that needs to be clicked first to uncover the underlying text field. So the following work for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import unittest


class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get(URL)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

def get_by_id(self, id):
    return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id))
    )
def test_input_text_in_rte(self):
    description_msg = "Hello There"
    rte_container = self.get_by_id('mui-rte-container')
    rte_label = rte_container.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Description:')]")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(rte_label)
    actions.click(rte_label)
    actions.perform()

    rte_input = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
            '//div[@class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" and @role="textbox"]'))
    )

    rte_input.send_keys(description_msg)
```

Thanks to @DebanjanB for the suggestions that are incorporated in the code above.